# ontoggle action in treeGrid Lightning Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The ontoggle action which returns parameters like '`name`', '`row`' etc. I am able to get the value for 'name' parameter. Like this,  `var rowName  = event.getParam('name');` but I am not able to get the value for 'row' parameter. Like,  `var abc = event.getParam('row');` It gives nothing.

Any idea how to solve this issue?